# on delete cascade error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

Im trying to include the `on delete cascade` on my table `idtabless` but im getting a error `Cannot add foreign key constraint` I don't know what can be the reason.

This is my main table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `courses` (
  `courseId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coursename` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`courseId`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=218 ;
```

I include the `on delete cascade` on this table and works fine

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `studentss` (
  `studentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `studentcode` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `courseid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentid`),
  KEY `courseid` (`courseid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;
```

and Im trying to do the same with the `idtabless` and is when i gt the error

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `idtabless` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `courseid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `studentid` char(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY fk_courses_id (courseid)
    REFERENCES courses (courseid)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatched data types.  Courses.courseid is integer and idtabless.courseid is varchar.  Change the latter to integer (11) and you'll be in business.